# The service "App\Decorator\DomainHydraDecorator" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.hydra.normalizer.error"

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm currently using `Symfony 4.4` and `API Platform 2.6.8`.

The problem is that the error format does not suit me, so I use the "decorate pattern" to override this, here is my configuration of services.yaml :

```
    App\Decorator\DomainHydraDecorator:
    decorates: 'api_platform.hydra.normalizer.error'
    arguments: [ '@App\Decorator\DomainHydraDecorator.inner' ]
```

The problem is that it gives me the following error:

```
The service "App\Decorator\DomainHydraDecorator" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.hydra.normalizer.error"
```

Indeed the service is not present, however in the vendors there is the file ErrorNormalizer. Can you help me? Are there any additional packages to install?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's good! I was missing this in the APIP configuration file:

```
formats:
    jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
```